# i sign in user already give the role and claim ,But always in mvc give me unauthorized 401 what should i do , there is something i should put in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

```
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "NewApp", Version = "v1" });
c.AddSecurityDefinition("BearerAuth", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Scheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.ToLowerInvariant(),
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = "Authorization",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."
            });

            c.OperationFilter<AuthResponsesOperationFilter>();
        });
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Open", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        });
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("DepartmentPolicy",
                policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim("dpartment");
                });
        });
      -
    }
```

I also have this:

```
public class AuthResponsesOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var attributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                         .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true));

        if (attributes.OfType<IAllowAnonymous>().Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        var authAttributes = attributes.OfType<IAuthorizeData>();

        if (authAttributes.Any())
        {
            operation.Responses["401"] = new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Unauthorized" };

            if (authAttributes.Any(att => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(att.Roles) || !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(att.Policy)))
            {
                operation.Responses["403"] = new OpenApiResponse { Description = "Forbidden" };
            }

            operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                        {
                            {
                                new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Id = "BearerAuth",
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                            }
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this should have a Swagger tag.

Comment: Try to use F12 developer tools or Fiddler to check the request header, whether it contains the JWT token or not? Besides, you can also try to decode the JWT token, whether it contains the claims or not?